# Inconsistent ValueError with timezone offset out of bounds

Tags: python, dataframe, python-dateutil

The timezone offset part of a timestamp must be between -12 and +14 hours. Otherwise it's nonsensical. I'm working with a field of timestamp strings in a pandas dataframe ad some of my timestamps are nonsensical due to the offset being out of this -12 + 14 hour boundary.

A good timestamp:

```
good = '2019-11-11T07:08:09.640-4:00'
```

A bad timezone offset

```
bad = '2019-11-19T22:51:34.619000+17:00'
```

Another bad timezone offset:

```
bad2 = '2019-11-11T07:08:09.640-31:00'
```

Now, if I try to convert these strings to isoformat:

Works as expected:

```
import dateutil
dateutil.parser.parse(good).isoformat()
'2019-11-11T07:08:09.640000-04:00'
```

Does not work as expected, returns a timestamp:

```
dateutil.parser.parse(bad).isoformat()
'2019-11-19T22:51:34.619000+17:00'
```

Works as expected, I get an error message (Which I could subsequently use in a if else, try, catch block)

```
dateutil.parser.parse(bad2).isoformat()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: offset must be a timedelta strictly between -timedelta(hours=24) and timedelta(hours=24).
```

Why do I get a error message on bad2 and not bad when they both have out of bounds time zone offsets

Comment: Note my goal is to get an exception on bad, not to correct the error on bad2

Comment: Because I need to format the dates, so I need to identify those that have nonsensical timezone offsets and bad does not give me a warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply the bounds of time zone offsets in Python - as noted in the error message, offsets are bounded to be at most ±24h, which is consistent with your findings. It is not related to the current maximum and minimum offsets in real time zones, other than the fact that it would be a problem if the bounds did *not* allow all real time zones to be represented.

There is no simple way to get datetime or dateutil to fail in the way you want because the bounds are not configurable. If you want to detect offsets outside +14/-12 or whatever arbitrary restriction, you'll need to check `utcoffset`, like so:

```
if not (timedelta(hours=-12) < dt.utcoffset() < timedelta(hours=14)):
    raise ValueError(...)
```

That said, I don't recommend this course of action unless you know that some of your strings have this particular error mode. One thing you will learn dealing with datetimes and time zones is that putting arbitrary restrictions on them is rarely a good idea, because some random country somewhere will decide to make a rule that violates your neat "practical" restriction. I am even mildly wary of the ±24h offset restriction in tzinfo, but that is built into the language and it is at least unlikely that a real offset will violate it any time soon.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for the answer. For more context, while I can seem to process my dataframe fine within pandas, the trouble is when I then try to push it to postgres using sql alchemy. The receiving table has a field of type timezone with offset. From the logs: `sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidTimeZoneDisplacementValue) time zone displacement out of range: "2019-11-19T22:51:34.619000+17:00"`
The -12 + 14 rule is not arbitrary... to my knowledge this is the only possible bound when the base timezone is utc.

Comment: I also don't feel comfortable trying to manually configure the offsets. I faintly recall working with ISO before and receiving a similar error message but rather than being within 24 hours it instead quoted the -14, +12 range. But I cannot remember which package that was

Comment: I'm also getting a syntax error with your block, if you ca see anything a miss let me know? ```def rogue_tz_offsets(t):
    if not (timedelta(hours=-12) < t.utcoffset() < timedelta(hours=14):
        return dateutil.parser.parse(t).replace(tzinfo=None).isoformat()
    else:
        return dateutil.parser.parse(t).isoformat()```

Comment: @DougFir I assume you got it sorted out by now, but I accidentally dropped a parenthesis in my original response, sorry about that.

Comment: @DougFir -12/+14 may be the *current* span of UTC offsets, but it is not necessarily the only possible span. Consider that the `+14` seems a bit odd, doesn't it, since that spans 26 hours, not 24. You could easily imagine a country deciding to switch from +10 to -14, for example, or any other arbitrary offset, for their own crazy reasons. It is dangerous for something like sqlalchemy to take a hard stand about the range of valid offsets.